# To merge the values of common columns in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is one data frame consisting of three columns: group, po, and part

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'group':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3],
       'po':['1a','1b','','','','','2a','2b','2c','','3a',''],
       'part':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l']})
```

[image]

by group column,
Po columns are common parts and I want to display them continuously using a slash('/')

like below dataframe

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can group the `po` values by `group`, aggregating them using `join` (with `filter` to discard empty values):

```py
df['po'] = df.groupby('group')['po'].transform(lambda g:'/'.join(filter(len, g)))
df
```

Output:

```
    group        po part
0       1     1a/1b    a
1       1     1a/1b    b
2       1     1a/1b    c
3       1     1a/1b    d
4       1     1a/1b    e
5       1     1a/1b    f
6       2  2a/2b/2c    g
7       2  2a/2b/2c    h
8       2  2a/2b/2c    i
9       2  2a/2b/2c    j
10      3        3a    k
11      3        3a    l
```